# Advice for setting up classes for a game

Tags: class, oop, design-patterns

I quite inexperienced with programming, and I've decided to work on a 2D rpg-style game as a personal project, and I am not sure how to set up classes within my game.

In particular I am having some issues with the 'room' classes. At the moment I want 2 types of rooms, stationary and scrolling. I have tried setting it up with a base class Room, with two subclasses, however I ran into issues.

For this kind of problem is it more usual to just have one class, and a couple of attributes that tell you whether the particular room is scrolling or not?
If it is better to use OOP, does anyone have any good resources that I could use to better get my head around it?

Thank you very much :))